# How to show the image outside the dialog in android?

Tags: android, layout, android-dialogfragment, android-framelayout

I trying to show the profile image in topside of the dialog fragment with half outside the image.and i attach the sample dialog in below, like that.And tried all FrameLayout collaboration from old Stackoverflow solutions, But i cant able to archive this. Please give me correct solution. Thankyou.

[image]

**Updated**
I also tried to make transparent the ImageView parent layout but it's not working in after dialog show. i attach my xml and result screen shot below.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_item"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/imageshow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/imagePadding"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imagePadding"
        android:background="#ff0000"></LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/info_profile"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/technician_pitcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DDfD.jpg)

Comment: make the dialog bg transparent. draw it as you want then.

Comment: Post your XML layout file for the dialog

Comment: transparent the background also i tried its not working. Please find out my updated question .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below `xml`

**custom_dialog_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rl_dialog_container"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp">

<View
    android:id="@+id/imagePadding"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/round_dialog_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/imagePadding"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/imagePadding2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp" />

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/dialog_image"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And when you are displaying your dialog, follow the code below:

```
     Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_layout);
            //The line below is important
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog.show();
```

Comment: i tried your way. i don't know why it's not working for me.. plz find out my update

Comment: It's working,it transparent the whole dialog. But i want to transparent particular part exactly for your previously uploaded pitcher.

Comment: The part that you don't want transparent,  add a background color to it. Just as I did in my `LinearLayout` with id `round_dialog_container`

Answer (score 1):

This will definitely help you try this.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/li1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </View>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/li1"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#ffd500"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

use this code inside Relative layout

Comment: Parent layout color transparent in not working in dialog

Comment: For making transparent the background in programmatically it's woking good.

Comment: use this link to make custom dialog you dont need to make parent layout transparent http://www.androidtutorials.info/2016/08/android-custom-poup-dialog.html#more

Answer (score 1):

This could be the simplest anwer?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl_alert_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="#00FFFFFF">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/alert_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:text="Your text goes here.." />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/alert_icon"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_alert_bell" />
</RelativeLayout>
```