# How to add an ImageView at the top of bottom sheet in android

Tags: android, layout, android-imageview, bottom-sheet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1TOD.png)I have an app in which I want to make a bottom sheet with an ImageView on the top of bottom sheet. How do I achieve this type of layout. Please help me

code of bottom sheet.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
android:paddingTop="8dp">

<!-- NOTE: This list should be displayed in a list
instead of nested layouts -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:tint="#737373" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Preview"
        android:textColor="#737373"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you solved it yet..?

Comment: No...................

Comment: See i have edited image as what i want

Comment: did you tried my below ans

Comment: yes i tried but main layout still visible

Comment: see this link exactly same i want to archeive.....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47688722/how-to-anchor-imageview-to-layout

Comment: but not want make layout as background......

Comment: try this than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44878784/how-to-show-the-image-outside-the-dialog-in-android

Comment: I mean when i tried below code it will showing inside layout i want to anchor in top of main layout

Comment: but how should i make this with Bottom sheet

Comment: here is code of bottom sheet....

Comment: BottomSheetFragment bottomSheetFragment = new BottomSheetFragment();
        bottomSheetFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),bottomSheetFragment.getTag());

Comment: check my updated ans

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
android:layout_gravity="center_Horizontal"
```

& Provide Padding to the Image
Using

```
android:padding="Size"
```

or

```
android:paddingLeft="Size"
android:paddingRight="Size"
```

> Also try Relative View to Set it Accordingly in Design View